Extended display settings not remembered when I change locations
I use my ASUS M515D laptop at three different locations with an extended monitor via HDMI, all monitors with the same resolution and dedicated to me. Every time I change from one client location to the next, Windows forgets my display settings and reverts to "Show only on 1." It is extremely frustrating to constantly have to reinstate the "extend these displays" setting as I move quite a lot between these three standard locations.
I looked on this forum and searched online in general, but did not find a solution.  Is there any way I can set up these monitors as standard equipment to be recognised?
